# OpenGL How does updating buffers affect speed

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I have a buffer I map to vertex attributes to send. Here is the basic functionality of the code:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _bufferID);
_buffer = (VertexData*)glMapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_WRITE_ONLY);

for(Renderable* renderable : renderables){
    const glm::vec3& size = renderable->getSize();
    const glm::vec3& position = renderable->getPosition();
    const glm::vec4& color = renderable->getColor();
    const glm::mat4& modelMatrix = renderable->getModelMatrix();
    glm::vec3 vertexNormal = glm::vec3(0, 1, 0);


    _buffer->position = glm::vec3(modelMatrix * glm::vec4(position.x, position.y, position.z, 1));
    _buffer->color = color;
    _buffer->texCoords = glm::vec2(0, 0);
    _buffer->normal = vertexNormal;
    _buffer++;
}
```

and then I draw all renderables in one draw call. I am curious as to why touching the `_buffer` variable at all causes massive slow down in the program. For example, if I call `std::cout << _buffer->position.x;` every frame, my fps tanks to about 1/4th of what it usually is.

What I want to know is why it does this. The reason I want to know is because I want to be able to give translate objects in the batch when they are moved. Essentially, I want the buffer to always be in the same spot and not change but I can change it without huge sacrifices to performance. I assume this isn't possible but I would like to know why. Here is an example of what I would want to do if this didn't cause massive issues:

```
if(renderables.at(index)->hasChangedPosition())
    _buffer+=index;
    _buffer->position = renderables.at(index)->getPosition();
```

I am aware I can send the transforms through the shader uniform but you can't do that for batched objects in one draw call.

Comment: @genpfault's answer is correct, but you also mentioned console IO (`std::cout << ...`). Console IO is RIDICULOUSLY slow and blocking. It should be avoided in a tight loop.

Comment: Also, you *can* send the transforms via a uniform array with instancing, which is what I assume you mean by "batching" since you also said you're drawing everything at once. See gl_InstanceID. (https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/gl_InstanceID.xhtml) That may not provide optimal performance since interleaved arrays tend to provide better cache behavior.

Comment: @3Dave Thank you so much for the additional information!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why touching the _buffer variable at all causes massive slow down in the program

...well, you *did* request a `GL_WRITE_ONLY` buffer; it's entirely possible that the GL driver set up the memory pages backing the pointer returned by `glMapBuffer()` with a custom [fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging#Page_faults) handler that actually goes out to the GPU to fetch the requested bytes, which can be...not fast.

Whereas if you only *write* to the provided addresses the driver/OS doesn't have to do anything until the `glUnmapBuffer()` call, at which point it can set up a nice, fast DMA transfer to blast the new buffer contents out to GPU memory in one go.